# Parsing code with python

Tags: python, regex, parsing, fortran

I am really new to python. So forgive anything dumb i say

I have a script that goes through a a fortran module line by line
it then does a .split() on each line and saves it to an array.
However .split() does not include newline characters, is there anyway for me to make it do that.

Also the way my code is written in the fortran module, for the most part is

```
integer x, & !comment
        y, & !comment 
        z    !comment
```

I do not want to include any comment text. I just want a list of the variables in the module.
is there anyway to use .split() or regex to achive this. Maybe only take the substring to the & followed by a comma?

Comment: If it goes through line by line, isn't each element in the array a new line in itself?

Comment: Can you please post the relevant code?

Comment: Its not because of the fact that its parses the comments into the array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are using "!" to start comments, I'm assuming you're using Fortran 90 or later.

You can use regular expressions to find variable declarations.

Here is a simple example to find `integer` variables:

```
In [1]: import re

In [2]: integer_re = re.compile('[ ]*integer[^:]*::\s+(.+)')

In [3]: progtext = '''  program average

  ! Read in some numbers and take the average
  ! As written, if there are no data points, an average of zero is returned
  ! While this may not be desired behavior, it keeps this example simple

  implicit none

  real, dimension(:), allocatable :: points
  integer                         :: number_of_points
  real                            :: average_points=0., positive_average=0., negative_average=0.

  write (*,*) "Input number of points to average:"
  read  (*,*) number_of_points

  allocate (points(number_of_points))

  write (*,*) "Enter the points to average:"
  read  (*,*) points

  ! Take the average by summing points and dividing by number_of_points
  if (number_of_points > 0) average_points = sum(points) / number_of_points

  ! Now form average over positive and negative points only
  if (count(points > 0.) > 0) then
     positive_average = sum(points, points > 0.) / count(points > 0.)
  end if

  if (count(points < 0.) > 0) then
     negative_average = sum(points, points < 0.) / count(points < 0.)
  end if

  deallocate (points)

  ! Print result to terminal
  write (*,'(a,g12.4)') 'Average = ', average_points
  write (*,'(a,g12.4)') 'Average of positive points = ', positive_average
  write (*,'(a,g12.4)') 'Average of negative points = ', negative_average

  end program average'''

In [4]: integer_re = re.compile('[ ]*integer[^:]*::\s+(.+)')

In [5]: integer_re.findall(progtext)
Out[5]: ['number_of_points']
```

The same can be done for the other types, e.g. real:

```
In [6]: real_re = re.compile('[ ]*real[^:]*::\s+(.*)')

In [7]: real_re.findall(progtext)
Out[7]: ['average_points=0., positive_average=0., negative_average=0.']
```

You could refine the regular expression to remove the initializers and get only the variable names. But it is probably easier just to split.

```
In [8]: real_re.findall(progtext)[0].split()
Out[8]: ['average_points=0.,', 'positive_average=0.,', 'negative_average=0.']
```

Or you can use another regex:

```
In [9]: re.findall('([a-z_]+)', real_re.findall(progtext)[0])
Out[9]: ['average_points', 'positive_average', 'negative_average']
```

Answer (score 1):

The way to do this is probably to use a buffer.

```
>>> s = """Some code with\n newlines and other stuff\n"""
>>> from StringIO import StringIO
>>> buffer = StringIO(s)
>>> list(buffer)
['Some code with\n', ' newlines and other stuff\n']
>>>
```

*Note*: In Python 3.x, replace `from StringIO import StringIO` with `from io import StringIO`.

## However...

I'm guessing that you're reading in the FORTRAN code from separate files using a Python `file` object. `file` objects already behave like buffers. Let's say that the file `whatever.f95` contains the text `Some code with\n newlines and other stuff\n`. Then you can simply do:

```
with open('whatever.f95') as f:
    print list(f)
```

Which will print

```
['Some code with\n', ' newlines and other stuff\n']
```

Comment: I'm guessing the problem the OP has is potentially with `str.split` itself, eg: `'Some code with\n'.split()` returns `['Some', 'code', 'with']` (and that maybe using `split(' ')` may be enough to solve it...)

Answer (score 0):

ufirstly to get an array of all the lines from the fortran script:

```
with open(fortran_script) as f:
    script = [i.strip() for i in f]
```

This will give you the array you require, with each line (stripped of the '\n') as a separate element.

Then, to remove the comments:

```
for i, line in enumerate(script):
        script[i] = line[:line.find('!')] if '!' in line else line
```

This will do the following:
    --> walk through each line, and test to see if it contains a comment;
    --> if there is a comment, the line is truncated to only include the preceding command

--- EDITS
It has been pointed out (see comments below) that this does not allow for the presence of '!' within strings. To allow for this, we need to parse each line individually and maintain memory of the 'state' we are in (i.e. `is_literal`):

```
output = []
def parse_fortran(script, output):
    for line in script:

        # flag to maintain state is_literal
        is_literal = False

        line_out = ''
        for c in line:

            # enter is_literal state if ' or " found
            if c == '"' or "'":
                is_literal = not is_literal

            # break to next line as soon as comment is reached
            elif c == '!' and not is_literal: 
                break

            # otherwise, add the statement to the output
            line_out += c
        output.append(line_out)
```

Hope this helps

Comment: `[i.strip() for i in f]` is sufficient. No need for the `readlines()` call.

Comment: also, `script = ['' if line.startswith('!') else line.split('!')[0] for line in script]` will achieve the last part with a list comprehension.

Comment: Nice - I like the list comprehension line above. Thanks! Will adjust the .readlines() part too.

Comment: What about comments in after a statement on the same line? And what about ! inside character literals?

Comment: That is a good point. In-line comments are accounted for `line[:line.find('!')]` will splice the line before the comment. However, you are right about '!' within strings, these are not accounted for. In this case, I think you would need to parse each line with a flag for strings.

Comment: I will further edit the above answer to allow for '!' within strings